# How do I change Clementine's play/pause indicator icons?

Tags: indicator, icons, panel, clementine

This is how the Clementine indicator displays play/pause:

[image][image]

It's a minor detail, but I feel that the play and pause icons just don't go with the monochrome design of the panel. In order to change them I tried to locate all files associated with clementine, but to no avail. Here's the output:

```
/home/user/.config/Clementine/clementine.db
/usr/bin/clementine
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/clementine:clementine.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/icons/application-x-clementine.png
/usr/share/applications/clementine.desktop
/usr/share/doc/clementine
/usr/share/doc/clementine/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/clementine/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/clementine/copyright
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/application-x-clementine.png
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/application-x-clementine.svg
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/apps/24/clementine-panel-grey.png
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/apps/24/clementine-panel.png
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/apps/24/clementine-panel-grey.png
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/apps/24/clementine-panel.png
/usr/share/man/man1/clementine.1.gz
/usr/share/menu/clementine
/usr/share/pixmaps/clementine-16.xpm
/usr/share/pixmaps/clementine.xpm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/clementine.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/clementine.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/clementine.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/clementine.postrm
/var/lib/menu-xdg/applications/menu-xdg/X-Debian-Applications-Sound-clementine.desktop
```

Can anyone tell me where to find these icons and how to change them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all sorry for my English, regarding the icons... 
I think that those icons are in the original source (no binary) in the "data" folder **(tiny-pause.png and tiny-start.png)**

You should download the source, here is the link:

git clone https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine.git && cd Clementine

And here you have a little instructions to compile it:

https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/wiki/Compiling-from-Source

Kind Regards.

Roman.

Comment: Your English is perfectly fine! Thank you very much for your answer, this solves my problem. I'll get onto changing the icons as soon as I have more time on my hands.